# How I can output data from request on my SPA using native XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, html, json, xmlhttprequest, single-page-application

I have a conditional html page and a conditional api.

GET request for user data in my api looks like this:

```
URL: {host}/user
Method: GET

Headers
- Content-Type: application/json
- Authorization: Bearer {token}
```

And the response:

```
Status: 200
Content-Type: application/json
Body:
{
    "first_name": "Ivan",
    "last_name": "Ivanov",
    "phone": "89001234567",
    "document_number": "1224567890"
}
```

How I can send the requests and output response data using XMLHttpRequest?

I try to use `xhr.response()` and it's work good, but when I try to `xhr.response()['first_name']` it don't work properly

Comment: Assuming you mean browser environment, you can use [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Answer (score 0):

I see two options given you have native JavaScript and jQuery available

The Fetch API

Or the older "standard" of [jQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp).

```
$.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt", success: function(result){
    $("#div1").html(result);
  }});
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was very simple.

Standart output of `xhr.response()`, where `xhr = new XMLHTTPRequest();` not a JSON, so I need to put `xhr.responseType = 'json'` before `xhr.open('POST', url)`